# mongodb multiple aggregates in same query, each with total

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Trying to do aggregate group with more than one **{ $sum: '$total' }**

```
db.transactions.aggregate([{$group: {_id: '$cashier', cost: {$sum: "$total"}}}, {$group:
{_id: '$deviceid', cost: {$sum: "$total"}}}  ])
```

When i use two aggregates, the second aggregate returns 0.
Av tried to use `$project` but still i loose get zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      cashier: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$cashier",
            cost: {
              $sum: "$total"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      deviceId: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$deviceid",
            cost: {
              $sum: "$total"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tkrl-Y9mh8N)

Comment: Bravooh !
I have removed `$project` and now using `$face`. It works well.
But just point of curiosity. Which of this 2 is reliable for heavy Load calls.

Comment: The `$facet` pipeline stage would cause problem with the BSON Limit only.